# Make the chat feed bots faster

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, chat

The chat feed bots have one significant drawback, they're very often just too late. As far as I understand, they just poll an RSS feed, and this might only happen around 30 minutes after the actual time something was posted.

This delay doesn't matter all that much in most cases, but sometimes it would be nice for the feeds to be actually on time. In some cases this delay causes certain relevant questions to be posted manually in chat, and then the feed bot will post them later again.

The delay also leads to an aggregation of posts, and the feed will just dump an entire screen full of posts if the site is a bit busier than usual. Making the feed more real-time would space out the posts better and avoid the huge question dumps that happen sometimes now.

There is also an existing mechanism that could be used for this, just like the RSS feeds. The live-updates web-socket-thingy should be able to supply chat with realtime updates for questions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yeah, the settings for how often and how many feeds at once are fetched were set when the volume was much lower; they were way too low for what we have these days. I've increased these values to better match reality, so the delay shouldn't be more than three minutes on average now.

Regarding your last paragraph, that's a much larger change than you make it sound. I'm not ruling out going into such a direction eventually, but I'm not currently planning on something like that.